# Weka Machine Learning: ARFF file: multiple relations

Tags: sqlite, arff

I have data in a SQLite database (about 7 tables with a few foreign keys between tables) which I would like to convert to the ARFF file format in order to input it to the Weka machine learning software.

Do I have to generate one ARFF file per SQLite table, or can I put multiple ARFF relations into one ARFF file?

Answer (score 2):

I think you will have to generate one per table because you will have to define a header for each table according to the [manual](http://statweb.stanford.edu/~lpekelis/13_datafest_cart/WekaManual-3-7-8.pdf) Chapter 10.

[Edit] More descriptive:

The ARFF files consist of a header and data. The file will consist of comments % , @RELATION, @ATTRIBUTE, and @DATA. The table object will be the relation, the column names will be the attributes and the column data will be the data. Attributes can be of different data types (Numeric, Nominal, Date, String, Relational). Nominal data types are strings that you define in curly brackets. They are usually used for the classification label. So your ARFF will look something like:

```
% Comments describing your data

@RELATION Table_Name

@ATTRIBUTE some_column NUMERIC
@ATTRIBUTE another_column DATE
@ATTRIBUTE class_label {it_could_be_this,it_could_be_that} %nominal attribute

@DATA

lines and lines of comma separated values.
```